# How can I change the style of the section number?

Tags: sectioning

The section appears like  "1 XXXXXXX", and I want something like "1. XXXX". I've been looking for some way to change it using \renewcommand, but nothing happens. Can you help me?
P.D. I am using the "Article" format.

Answer (score 0):

Load the `titlesec` package, and add `\titlelabel{\thetitle.\enspace}` to your preamble.